# Widget textarea input gets formatted

Tags: widgets

I've built a small widget for my website 
It has a couple of inputs, and a `<textarea>` among others. 
Whenever someone inputs to the textarea it adds a tab at the begining 
and changes every ' to \' 
After a couple of times I save the same input, 
I just get sentences that were

> It's nice

to

> It\\\\'s nice

the code for the Textrea:

```
         <textarea rows="5" cols="40" id="cat_<?php echo $i ?>_text" name="cat_<?php echo $i ?>_text">
        <?php echo $text ?>
        </textarea>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to remove the backslash.

```
echo stripslashes( $text );
```

This is going to replace one slash per slashes group only though, you should first reset all the contents that have multiple slashes.

I guess the tab at the beginning is due to the fact that you jump a line before echoing the text. Try this instead :

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="40" id="cat_<?php echo $i ?>_text" name="cat_<?php echo $i ?>_text"><?php echo stripslashes( $text ); ?></textarea>
```